# Do large aircraft have carbon monoxide detectors?

Tags: safety, airliner, aircraft-systems

Do big aircraft (e.g. Boeing 737 or Airbus 320) have carbon monoxide (CO) detectors installed in them? I don't know if the pressurized cabin means they aren't needed, but I do remember there are CO detectors in small planes and there are some reported accidents due to inhaling CO from engines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't seen any. Cabin heating is done quite differently on jet aircraft than on pistons. Bleed air is taken from the engine before the combustion chamber, so engine exhaust can't end up in the cabin, even if there was a greater fault in the A/C packs.

Comment: There are things that can get into the AC ducts by way of the packs, but CO isn't one of them.  I've had hydraulic fluid from an overserviced resevoir get into an AC pack through a torn seal, and that stank up the cabin pretty bad, and any FOD (like a bird) that gets into the engine's bleed air system will go through the pack and come out smelling bad, but CO, as a product of combustion, happens downstream of where the bleed air for the AC is taken out.  I've never seen a CO detector in a large turbine aircraft either.

Comment: It doesn't have to be exhaust gases- there is potential for smoldering small amounts of insulation.